# #1064 - check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, events, stored-procedures

hi i new in Stored Procedures and want test a procedure for get all the event from my table.

Here is my procedure:

[image]

here is the error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `;`

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllEvents()
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM VERANSTALUNG;    -- here
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9af4/1/0)**</kbd>